# INSERT связанных данных в несколько таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть следующие таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id integer,
    name varchar(100),
    info varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE shop (
    id integer,
    name varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE user_shop_m2m (
    user_id integer,
    shop_id integer
);
```

И предположим, что есть данные для добавления новых пользователей:

```
users = [
    {name: 'John', info: 'Info for John', shops: [1, 2, 3]},
    {name: 'Jane', info: 'Info for Jane', shops: [3, 4, 5]},
]
```

необходимо добавить эти данные в вышеупомянутые таблицы. Данных очень много и делать это в цикле на стороне приложения очень медленно. Добавить "пользователей" можно просто одним INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO user (
  "name",
  "info"
)
VALUES (
    ("John", "Info for John"),
    ("Jane", "Info for Jane"),
)
ON CONFLICT (
    "name",
)
DO UPDATE SET value=EXCLUDED.value
RETURNING *
```

Но вот ума не приложу как потом добавить данные shops в связующую таблицу user_shop_m2m еще одним INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью CTE можно сделать так:

```sql
WITH new_data(name, info, shop_ids) AS (
  VALUES
  ('John', 'Info for John', ARRAY[1, 2, 3])
, ('Jane', 'Info for Jane', ARRAY[3, 4, 5])
), inserted(user_id, name, info) AS (
  INSERT INTO "user" (name, info)
  SELECT name, info
    FROM new_data
  ON CONFLICT (name) DO
  UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name
  RETURNING id, name, info
), new_references(user_id, shop_id) AS (
  SELECT inserted.user_id, UNNEST(new_data.shop_ids)
    FROM inserted
    JOIN new_data
   USING (name, info)
)
INSERT INTO user_shop_m2m
SELECT * FROM new_references;
```

Берём новые данные, вставляем из них в таблицу пользователей, собираем данные для таблицы связей, и вставляем. Предполагается, что колонка `name` у вас уникальна.

Comment: Спасибо, в общем понятно, да колонка name уникальна, а есть ли какое-то решение в случае если она не уникальна и уникален только id в таблице user (для общего развития интересуюсь)

Comment: Мне кажется, что нет. Если у вас, например, запись с Джоном будет повторяться два раза, и все данные те же, кроме магазинов, то просто семантически непонятно, в чём различие между двумя Джонами. Таких проблем можно избежать, если использовать, например, UUIDv4.

Comment: @triplustri *есть ли какое-то решение в случае если она не уникальна и уникален только id в таблице user (для общего развития интересуюсь)* Нет, передаваемые данные не позволяют различить, какому из тёзок предназначена информация.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO user_shop_m2m (user_id, shop_id)
SELECT u.user_id, s.shop_id
FROM ( SELECT user_id 
       FROM user
       WHERE name = 'John'
       /*  AND info = 'Info for John' */ ) u,
     ( SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3] shop_id ) s
```

Comment: Спасибо. Насколько я понял тут пример как добавить shops для конкретного пользователя, а как это будет выглядеть для всех тех которые были затронуты в результате INSERT в таблицу user?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @triplustri Данный запрос выполняется ПОСЛЕ добавления пользователя - то есть в момент, когда пользователь в таблице пользователей гарантированно присутствует, причём в том состоянии, которое соответствует переданным данным. Ваш вопрос непонятен...