# Лучшая практика для вставки данных в связанные таблицы

Tags: postgresql

Как лучше инсертить кортежи в связные таблицы?
Мудрить с with [INSERT связанных данных в несколько таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011305/insert-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86) ?
Или транзакции?
Или прям тупо по очереди делать несколько запросов, храня в переменных яп промежуточные данные?

Comment: прям тупо по очереди делать несколько запросов, храня в переменных яп промежуточные данные, но в одной транзакции.

Comment: Зачем транзакции городить? PostgreSQL вполне себе поддерживает INSERT в CTE и, соответственно, RETURNING - так и вставлять.